# OrientDB Do I need to extend from V for embedded only classes?

Tags: orientdb

I have many small classes that are only going to be used as EMBEDDED classes. Do I need to extend each one of these small classes from V?

Example: I have a main class Driver and it has an EMBEDDED class Ticket. The Ticket class will never be used, searched or triversed outside of the Driver - it's only used as an embedded object for data structure. When I create this Ticket class, do I need to Extend it from V. If so, what are the reasons?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extend V, in this case it will be a ODocument.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks.